# get all fields in UpdateView django

Tags: django, field

Is it possible to get all the fields from a given `model` without writing list of all the fields in the `view.py` file when working with `UpdateView` in class-based views?

```
class UserProfileEditView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'level', 'course', 'country', 'title', 'avatar', 'icon', 'instagram']
    slug_field = 'username'
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'User'
```

What I mean is instead of writing all the fields in a list (e.g 'first_name', 'last_name'... etc.), can I use something to get all of the fields from given model.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Post your existing code please.

Comment: you can use model form which will give you all updateable fields of model.

Comment: You can use  `put` method if you want to update partially.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `fields` attribute on a generic class-based view works the same as it does on a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use). You can explicitly list the fields yourself, or you can use `__all__`, which indicates that all fields from the model should be used.

```
class UserProfileEditView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = '__all__'
    ...
```